# Make Matlab issue a warning when converting a double to a uint8 and vice versa?

Tags: matlab, casting

Typically in Matlab colours are represented by three element vectors of RGB intensity values, with precision uint8 (range 0 - 255) or double (range 0 - 1). Matlabs functions such as `imshow` work with either representation making both easy to use in a program.

It is equally easy however to introduce a bug when assigning colour values from a matrix of one type, to that of another (because the value is converted silently, but not re-scaled to the new range). Having just spent a number of hours finding such a bug, I would like to make sure it is never introduced again.

**How do I make Matlab display a warning when type conversion takes place?**

Ideally it would only be when the conversion is between `double` and `uint8`. It should also be difficult to deactivate (i.e. the option is not reset when loading a workspace, or when matlab crashes).

Comment: *Having just spent a number of hours finding such a bug [...]* I feel your pain. MATLAB's weak type system is what made me switch to Julia...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution is to define your own `uint8` function that casts to `uint8` and issues a warning if some value has been truncated.

You should place this function in a folder where it shadows the builtin `uint8` funciton. For example, your user folder is a good choice, as it usually appears the first in `path`.

Or, as noted by Sam Roberts, if you want this function to be called *only when converting from `double`* into `uint8` (not when converting from any other type into `uint8`), put it in a folder named `@double` within your path.

```
function y = uint8(x)
y = builtin('uint8', x);
if any(x(:)>255) || any(x(:)<0)
    warning('MATLAB:castTruncation', 'Values truncated during conversion to uint8')
end
```

The warning is on by default. You can switch it on or off with the commands `warning('on','MATLAB:castTruncation')` and `warning('off','MATLAB:castTruncation')` (thanks to CitizenInsane for the suggestion).

Comment: Adding a identifier to the warning will help to temporary disable it (on purpose of course).

Comment: @sebf A warning in the `uint8` to `double` direction wouldn't make much sense, because there's no truncation when going to `double`. That's why I've only covered the `double` to `uint8` part in my answer

Comment: @LuisMendo Even better, put this function in a folder on the path named `@double`. Then it will only get called when you convert `double` to `uint8` - at the moment it will be called when you convert _anything_ (e.g. `single` or `uint32`) to `uint8`.

Comment: @SamRoberts Are you suggesting shadowing built-in MATLAB stuff on purpose? Now that would be nasty...

Comment: @Jubobs Luis' answer is already suggesting shadowing the built-in `uint8`. I'm suggesting that instead of implementing it as a regular function, which will shadow the built-in `uint8` for _everything_, we implement it as a method of `double`, which will then only shadow the built-in `uint8` for doubles. PS as long as you know what you're doing, it's perfectly fine to do this - not nasty at all,

Comment: @SamRoberts Good point! I didn't know that. I've included it in my answer. Thanks

Comment: @SamRoberts Indeed, intentional shadowing is what Luis does, here. I just don't find that to be good style. If you know what you're doing, that may be fine, but that leads to too much confusion as soon as you share your code.

Comment: @Jubobs Agreed. I would have liked a more elegant solution, but I couldn't find any

Comment: @Jubobs I would certainly not suggest doing this sort of thing if I were sharing the code. Doing nothing extra but issuing a warning probably isn't that big a deal - but anything more, and it could very easily break other people's products in an antisocial way. If I were sharing the code, I'd address the issue properly, using `assert` and unit testing to ensure that inappropriate type conversions weren't taking place.

Comment: Thank you Luis! Very clever for sure - this is what I will do. Sam/Jubobs - surely this fix should be placed in a location such that it persists no matter what project is being worked on - and therefore *not* redistributed with individual projects, modifying only and individuals installation. I do not see anything nasty about it - to me its much the same as copying over the files of a plugin for apps that support such things.